# Stop MongoDB Atlas from creating extra unique index

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to stop mongodb atlas from auto-create unique index on emailacct field when save from nodejs? I deleted the emailacct index but it still create one when I did a save from nodejs. Thanks

[image]

Comment: do you use mongoose to define schema?

Comment: thanks for the reminder. I missed it. thanks agin